# React Data Table Lazy Loading or Pagination Loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-data-table-component

I am using react-data-table-component the data will be fetched from a API (which has 10k+ records).

```
async function getAllData() {
  let nextUrl = "/url/";
  let temp = [];
  let config = {
    headers: {
        Authorization: `token`,
    },
  };
  while (nextUrl !== null) {
    const response = await apiInstance.get(nextUrl, config);
    nextUrl = response.data.next;
    temp.push(...response.data.results);
  }
  return temp;
}

async function tempFunc() {
  let temp1 = await getAllData();
  setDataFromAPI(temp1); // useState
}

tempFunc();
```

// DataTable

```
<DataTable
    pagination
    columns={columns}
    data={dataFromAPI}
    customStyles={customStyles}
/>
```

Right now this function works fine, the problem is the api has 10k+ records, the page is loading until it finishes the while loop.

Instead of this, i wanted to load only the first 30 or 50 then onnext pagination i would like to load the next response.

How can this be done ?

Comment: Are you able to send pagination info (like page-number, number-of-rows-per-page, etc) on the API request? In my fairly-brief ReactJS experience, have seen APIs that support it & hence the question.

Comment: `{count: 5,
next: null, // url
previous: null, //url, results: [{},{}]}`

api response

Comment: Just before `temp.push(...response.data.results)` could you try something like `setDataFromAPI(prevDataFromAPI => ([...prevDataFromAPI, ...response.data.results]));` ? The objective is to update the state with each batch-of-results, in a piece-meal way.

Comment: yep, that's fine but it will hit the api 10k+ times, how to avoid that ?

Comment: This loop: `while (nextUrl !== null)`, terminates when `nextUrl` becomes `null`. If you need to restrict the number of API calls, simply add a counter within the loop and terminate the loop when counter reaches a threshold (say 30, or 50). Make arrangements to safe-keep the `nextUrl` from the API response to be used when making the next API call. Try it & if still support is required, let us know.